# Importing large multilayer TIFF as NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to load a 3D TIFF image as a NumPy array. I am unable to load slices for large indices, and the maximum index size depends on the size of the arrays. For example, using a stack of 2048x2048 images, I cannot load images after the 256th=2^8th. For a stack of 1024x1024, I cannot load images after the 1024=2^10th. i.e. in either case I can only access the first 2^31 bytes of the TIF image. Note that I am only trying to load a single image from the stack.

I am using python 3.7.5, NumPy version 1.17.4, and PIL version 6.2.1 on Windows 10 on a machine with 8Gb of RAM.

Minimal example reproducing the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# generate test image
fname = r"test.tif"
img = np.random.randint(2**16, size=(257, 2048, 2048), dtype=np.uint16)

# save test image
im_list = [Image.fromarray(img[ii].astype('uint16')) for ii in range(img.shape[0])]
im_list[0].save(fname, save_all=True, append_images=im_list[1:])

# load image
im_loaded = Image.open(fname)

# this succceeds
im_loaded.seek(255)
arr255 = np.asarray(im_loaded, dtype=np.uint16)

# this fails
im_loaded.seek(256)
arr256 = np.asarray(im_loaded, dtype=np.uint16)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-107-3430f5720c7e>", line 2, in <module>
    arr256 = np.asarray(im_loaded, dtype=np.uint16)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TiffImageFile'
```

This seems to be a PIL issue, as I can successfully read the TIFF file using other tools. In particular, [libtiff](https://pypi.org/project/libtiff/)

```
import libtiff
tif = libtiff.TIFF.open(fname, 'r')
for ii, tif_slice in enumerate(tif.iter_images()):
    if ii == 256:
        arr = np.asarray(tif_slice, dtype=np.uint16)
```

Comment: [Pillow's memory mapping interface on Windows uses 32-bit integers](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/map.c) such that it can only access up to 2 GB. I think using Python memmap instead will fix this issue.

Comment: Fixed at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4310

Comment: Great, thank you for the quick fix @cgohlke! Figured it had to be something along those lines.

Comment: @cgohlke's code change has been merged, so this should be fixed in Pillow 8.2.0, due to be released on April 1